# How to get equal spaces within each property in JSON using GSON?

Tags: java, json, gson

I am using Gson to play with JSON. In my below code:

```
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
jsonObject.addProperty("fname", "john");
jsonObject.addProperty("lname", "cena");
System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());
```

It prints out like this:

```
{"fname":"john","lname":"cena"}
```

How can I get stuff printed like this instead in the below format. As you can see, I have spaces and everything properly.

```
{"fname" : "john", "lname" : "cena"}
```

Comment: JSON doesn't care about spaces outside of quotes... Why do you need this?

Comment: There is no reason to do this that I can think of. However, if you have to it should be easy to create a wrapper for `JsonObject` and override the `toString` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gson's pretty printing.  JSON.org's library has something similar as well. (I'm sure Jackson does as well).  Note: this will also format it so it's very readable.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String json = gson.toJson(obj);
System.out.println(json);
```